# Optimize Center of Circle given noisy data points on arbitrary Plane

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry, cloud, point

I don't seem to find an algorithm to calculate the center of a circle given a set of noisy data (on the circumference of the circle) on an arbitrary Plane in 3D.
I did try different approached as to calculating the center by only taking 3 points at a time and then averaging the centers, yet I believe there must be a better solution to optimize the center by minimizing the distance to all points.
Does anyone have an Idea?

Any Ideas or approaches would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How many points do you have? You can sum up the distance from point p to all given points and try to minimize this. For this kind of problem the downhill simplex algorithm converges pretty fast, but you have to calculate this summed up distance multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found several Solutions adjusting my search terms:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/475212-circle-least-squares-fit-for-3d-data

https://jekel.me/2015/Least-Squares-Sphere-Fit/

Both Approaches work very well. In the second link you have to calculate the plane first, which can be done using SVD. Basically I think both approaches are very similar and produce basically the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

I have an auxiliary structure (called Aprox) that contains Center, Radius (I use its square for speed optimization) and Boundary points (two or three).

I have the following functions:

CircumscribedCircle_2Points(P1, P2):Aprox (center of the line segment in 3D)

CircumscribedCircle_3Points(P1, P2, P3):Aprox (center of the circle traced ), programmed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products

CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($Aprox, $Pnt):boolean (It is in the given Approx)

I compute Aprox from the first two points and then run through the other points. If it's in circle I do nothing, if it's out I calculate a new Aprox and run through again (all points).
The rule is: If there are 4 points in the plane, one of them is always inside the circle given by the other three.

```
function CircumscribedCircle_2Points($P1, $P2,
  $Aprox=[])
{
$Aprox = as_New('Borders', [$P1, $P2]);
$Aprox['Center'] = v3d_AvgV3($P1, $P2);
$Aprox['RadSq'] = v3d_mV3AbsKv($Aprox['Center'], $P1);
$Aprox['RadSq'] = $Aprox['RadSq'] + 0.0001; //Float rounding errors
return $Aprox;
}

function CircumscribedCircle_3Points($P1, $P2, $P3,
  $Aprox=[],$JmP=0,$Jm=0,$u1=0,$u2=0,$u3=0)
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products
{
$Aprox = as_New('Borders', [$P1, $P2, $P3]);
$JmP = v3d_Abs(v3d_vxV3(v3d_mV3($P1,$P2),v3d_mV3($P2,$P3)));
$Jm = 2 * $JmP**2;
$u1 = v3d_mV3AbsKv($P2,$P3) * v3d_sxV3(v3d_mV3($P1,$P2),v3d_mV3($P1,$P3)) / $Jm;
$u2 = v3d_mV3AbsKv($P1,$P3) * v3d_sxV3(v3d_mV3($P2,$P1),v3d_mV3($P2,$P3)) / $Jm;
$u3 = v3d_mV3AbsKv($P1,$P2) * v3d_sxV3(v3d_mV3($P3,$P1),v3d_mV3($P3,$P2)) / $Jm;
$Aprox['Center'] = v3d_pV3pV3(v3d_xSkl($P1,$u1), v3d_xSkl($P2,$u2), v3d_xSkl($P3,$u3));
$Aprox['RadSq'] = v3d_mV3AbsKv($P1,$P2) * v3d_mV3AbsKv($P2,$P3) * v3d_mV3AbsKv($P3,$P1) / (2*$JmP)**2;
$Aprox['RadSq'] = $Aprox['RadSq'] + 0.0001; //Float rounding errors
return $Aprox;
}

function CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($Aprox, $Pnt)
{
return v3d_mV3AbsKv($Aprox['Center'], $Pnt) <= $Aprox['RadSq'];
}


function CircumscribedCircle_SetAprox($Aprox, $Pnt,
  $HrLen=0,$i=0,$TestAprox=[],$Ok=true,$j=0, $TestRet=[])
{
$HrLen=ar_Count($Aprox['Borders']); //2 or 3
for ($i=0; $i<$HrLen; $i++)
  {
  $TestAprox = CircumscribedCircle_2Points($Aprox['Borders'][$i], $Pnt);
  $Ok = true;
  for ($j=0; $j<$HrLen; $j++)
    {
    if ($i==$j) continue;
    if (CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($TestAprox, $Aprox['Borders'][$j])) continue;
    $Ok = false;
    break;
    }
  if ($Ok) return $TestAprox;
  }
if ($HrLen==2)
  {
  return CircumscribedCircle_3Points($Aprox['Borders'][0], $Aprox['Borders'][1], $Pnt);
  }
$TestRet = ar_New();
$TestAprox = CircumscribedCircle_3Points($Aprox['Borders'][0], $Aprox['Borders'][1], $Pnt);
if (CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($TestAprox, $Aprox['Borders'][2])) ar_Push($TestRet, $TestAprox);
$TestAprox = CircumscribedCircle_3Points($Aprox['Borders'][0], $Aprox['Borders'][2], $Pnt);
if (CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($TestAprox, $Aprox['Borders'][1])) ar_Push($TestRet, $TestAprox);
$TestAprox = CircumscribedCircle_3Points($Aprox['Borders'][1], $Aprox['Borders'][2], $Pnt);
if (CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($TestAprox, $Aprox['Borders'][0])) ar_Push($TestRet, $TestAprox);
ar_Sort($TestRet, function($a, $b){return $a['RadSq']-$b['RadSq'];});
return $TestRet[0];
}

function CircumscribedCircle($Arr,
  $Aprox=[], $i=0, $l=0, $max=0)
{
$Aprox = CircumscribedCircle_2Points($Arr[0], $Arr[1]);
for ($i=0, $l=ar_Count($Arr); $i<$l; $i++)
  {
  if (CircumscribedCircle_IsIn($Aprox, $Arr[$i])) continue;
  $Aprox = CircumscribedCircle_SetAprox($Aprox, $Arr[$i]);
  if (!$Aprox) return false;
  $i=-1;
  }
return as_New('Center',$Aprox['Center'], 'Radius', nm_Sqrt($Aprox['RadSq']));
}

//-------------------------
in JS
const x = 0;
const y = 1;
const z = 2;
in PHP
define('x', 0);
define('y', 1);
define('z', 2);

function v3d_AvgV3($v, $w)
//Diameter of two vectors (center of the line segment)
{
return ar_New(($v[x]+$w[x])/2, ($v[y]+$w[y])/2, ($v[z]+$w[z])/2);
}

function v3d_Abs($v)
//Absolute vector size
{
return nm_Sqrt($v[x]**2 + $v[y]**2 + $v[z]**2);
}

function v3d_vxV3($v,$w)
//Vector product
{
return ar_New($v[y]*$w[z]-$w[y]*$v[z], $v[z]*$w[x]-$w[z]*$v[x], $v[x]*$w[y]-$w[x]*$v[y]);
}

function v3d_mV3Abs($v, $w)
//Vector difference
{
return nm_Sqrt(($v[x]-$w[x])**2 + ($v[y]-$w[y])**2 + ($v[z]-$w[z])**2);
}

function v3d_mV3AbsKv($v, $w)
//Square of vector difference
{
return ($v[x]-$w[x])**2 + ($v[y]-$w[y])**2 + ($v[z]-$w[z])**2;
}

function v3d_sxV3($v,$w)
//Scalar product
{
return $v[x]*$w[x] + $v[y]*$w[y] + $v[z]*$w[z];
}

function v3d_pV3pV3($v,$w,$u)
//Sum 3 3D vect
{
return ar_New($v[x]+$w[x]+$u[x], $v[y]+$w[y]+$u[y], $v[z]+$w[z]+$u[z]);
}

function v3d_xSkl($v,$k)
//3D vect multiple scalar
{
return ar_New($v[x]*$k, $v[y]*$k, $v[z]*$k);
}
```

The code is universal and works both in PHP and Javascript :-) I declare auxiliary variables as optional parameters (to avoid using var keyword)

as_* are functions related to associative arrays, ar_* are functions related to numeric arrays, nm_* is numeric and their function is clear from their name. v3d_* are functions related to 3d vectors and are listed in the footnote.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)